# plotmplier in NARDL package

Tags: r

I have a problem with running plotmplier command in NARDL package. I keep receiving the same error:

> error in plot.window(…) :need finite ylim

```
erd22 <- nardl(ef~lwr,efo,ic="bic",maxlags = TRUE,graph = FALSE,case=3) summary(erd22)
plotmplier(erd22,2,2,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Result through NARDL in R Prog is contradicted with  Stata and Eviews. F Bound test is not a correct one. Better to use Stata or eviews 9/10.